# Bilinear image interpolation / scaling - A calculation example

Tags: image, image-processing, interpolation, image-scaling, linear-interpolation

I would like to ask you about some bilinear interpolation / scaling details. Let's assume that we have this matrix:

```
|100 | 50 |
|70  | 20 |
```

This is a 2 x 2 grayscale image.  Now, I would like scale it by factor of two and my matrix looks like this:

```
| 100   | f1 | 50 | f2 |
| f3    | f4 | f5 | f6 |
| 70    | f7 | 20 | f8 |
```

so if we would like to calculate `f4`, the calculation is defined as

```
f1 = 100 + 0.5(50 - 100) = 75
f7 = 70 +  0.5(20 - 70) = 45
```

and now finally:

```
f4 = 75 + 0.5(45 - 75) = 60
```

However, I can't really understand what calculations are proper for **f3** or **f1**

Do we do the bilinear scaling in each direction separately?  Therefore, this would mean that:

```
f3 = 100 + 0.5(70 - 100) = 85
f1 = 100 + 0.5(50 - 100) = 75
```

Also, how should I treat **f2, f6, f8**. Are those points simply being copied like in the nearest neighbor algorithm?

Comment: When I rescale with bilinear interpolation then I leave the corner point as corner points ...  so the formulas are the same for all points (but the scale is a bit tricky). Otherwise you need to extrapolate the enlarged area after known points creating artifacts in gradients at these points....

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would like to point you to this very insightful graphic from Wikipedia that illustrates how to do bilinear interpolation for one point:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation)</sup>

As you can see, the four red points are **what is known**.  These points you know before hand and `P` is the point we wish to interpolate.  As such, we have to do two steps (as you have indicated in your post).  To handle the `x` coordinate (horizontal), we must calculate what the interpolated value is row wise for the top row of red points and the bottom row of red points.  This results in the two blue points `R1` and `R2`. To handle the `y` coordinate (vertical), we use the two blue points and interpolate vertically to get the final `P` point.

When you resize an image, even though we don't visually see what I'm about to say, but imagine that this image is a **3D signal** `f`.  Each point in the matrix is in fact a 3D coordinate where the column location is the `x` value, the row location is the `y` value and the `z` value is the quantity / grayscale value of the matrix itself.  Therefore, doing `z = f(x,y)` is the value of the matrix at location `(x,y)` in the matrix.  In our case, because you're dealing with images, each value of `(x,y)` are integers that go from 1 up to as many rows/columns as we have depending on what dimension you're looking at.

Therefore, given the coordinate you want to interpolate at `(x,y)`, and given the red coordinates in the image above, which we call them `x1,y1,x2,y2` as per the diagram - specifically going with the convention of the diagram and referencing how images are accessed: `x1 = 1, x2 = 2, y1 = 2, y2 = 1`, the blue coordinates `R1` and `R2` are computed via 1D interpolation column wise using the same row both points coincide on:

```
R1 = f(x1,y1) + (x - x1)/(x2 - x1)*(f(x2,y1) - f(x1,y1))
R2 = f(x1,y2) + (x - x1)/(x2 - x1)*(f(x2,y2) - f(x1,y2))
```

It's important to note that `(x - x1) / (x2 - x1)` is a **weight / proportion** of how much of a mix the output consists of between the two values seen at `f(x1,y1)` and `f(x2,y1)` for `R1` or `f(x1,y2)` and `f(x2,y2)` for `R2`.  Specifically, `x1` is the starting point and `(x2 - x1)` is the difference in `x` values.  You can verify that substituting `x1` as `x` gives us 0 while `x2` as `x` gives us 1.  This weight fluctuates between `[0,1]` which is required for the calculations to work.

It should be noted that the origin of the image **is at the top-left corner**, and so `(1,1)` is at the top-left corner.  Once you find `R1` and `R2`, we can find `P` by interpolating row wise:

```
P = R2 + (y - y2)/(y2 - y1)*(R1 - R2)
```

Again, `(y - y2) / (y2 - y1)` denote the proportion / mix of how much `R1` and `R2` contribute to the final output `P`.  As such, you calculated `f5` correctly because you used four known points: The top left is 100, top right is 50, bottom left is 70 and bottom right is 20.  Specifically, if you want to compute `f5`, this means that `(x,y) = (1.5,1.5)` because we're halfway in between the 100 and 50 due to the fact that you're scaling the image by two.  If you plug in these values into the above computation, you will get the value of 60 as you expected.  The weights for both calculations will also result in `0.5`, which is what you got in your calculations and that's what we expect.

If you compute `f1`, this corresponds to `(x,y) = (1.5,1)` and if you substitute this into the above equation, you will see that `(y - y2)/(y2 - y1)` gives you 0 or the weight is 0, and so what is computed is just `R2`, corresponding to the linear interpolation along the top row only.  Similarly, if we computed `f7`, this means we want to interpolate at `(x,y) = (1.5,2)`.  In this case, you will see that `(y - y2) / (y2 - y1)` is 1 or the weight is 1 and so `P = R2 + (R1 - R2)`, which simplifies to `R1` and is the linear interpolation along the bottom row only.

Now there's the case of `f3` and `f5`.  Those both correspond to `(x,y) = (1,1.5)` and `(x,y) = (2,1.5)` respectively.  Substituting these values in for `R1` and `R2` and `P` for both cases give:

#### `f3`

```
R1 = f(1,2) + (1 - 1)/(2 - 1)*(f(2,2) - f(1,2)) = f(1,2)
R2 = f(1,1) + (1 - 1)/(2 - 1)*(f(1,2) - f(1,1)) = f(1,1)
P = R1 + (1.5 - 1)*(R1 - R2) = f(1,2) + 0.5*(f(1,2) - f(1,1))

P = 70 + 0.5*(100 - 70) = 85
```

#### `f5`

```
R1 = f(1,2) + (2 - 1)/(2 - 1)*(f(2,2) - f(1,2)) = f(2,2)
R2 = f(1,1) + (2 - 1)/(2 - 1)*(f(1,2) - f(1,1)) = f(1,2)
P = R1 + (1.5 - 1)*(R1 - R2) = f(2,2) + 0.5*(f(2,2) - f(1,2))

P = 20 + 0.5*(50 - 20) = 35
```

So what does this tell us?  This means that you are interpolating **along the y-direction only**.  This is apparent when we take a look at `P`.  Examining the calculations more thoroughly of `P` for each of `f3` and `f5`, you see that we are considering values along the vertical direction only.

*As such, if you want a definitive answer, `f1` and `f7` are found by interpolating along the `x` / column direction only along the same row.  `f3` and `f5` are found by interpolating `y` / row direction along the same column.  `f4` uses a mixture of `f1` and `f7` to compute the final value as you have already seen.*

---

To answer your final question, `f2`, `f6` and `f8` are filled in based on personal preference.  These values are considered to be out of bounds, with the `x` and `y` values both being `2.5` and that's outside of our `[1,2]` grid for `(x,y)`.  In MATLAB, the default implementation of this is to fill any values outside of the defined boundaries to be not-a-number (`NaN`), but sometimes, people extrapolate using linear interpolation, copy the border values, or perform some elaborate padding like symmetric or circular padding.  It depends on what situation you're in, but there is no correct and definitive answer on how to fill in `f2`, `f6` and `f8` - it all depends on your application and what makes the most sense to you.

---

As a bonus, we can verify that my calculations are correct in MATLAB.  We first define a grid of `(x,y)` points in the `[1,2]` range, then resize the image so that it's twice as large where we specify a resolution of 0.5 per point rather than 1.  I'm going to call your defined matrix `A`:

```
A = [100 50; 70 20]; %// Define original matrix
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:2,1:2); %// Define original grid of points
[X2,Y2] = meshgrid(1:0.5:2.5,1:0.5:2.5) %// Define expanded grid of points
B = interp2(X,Y,A,X2,Y2,'linear'); %// Perform bilinear interpolation
```

The original `(x,y)` grid of points looks like:

```
>> X

X =

     1     2
     1     2

>> Y

Y =

     1     1
     2     2
```

The expanded grid to expand the size of the matrix by twice as much looks like:

```
>> X2

X2 =

    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000
    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000
    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000
    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000

>> Y2

Y2 =

    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000
    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000
    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000
```

`B` is the output using `X` and `Y` as the original grid of points and `X2` and `Y2` are the points we want to interpolate at.

We get:

```
>> B

B =

   100    75    50   NaN
    85    60    35   NaN
    70    45    20   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: How will we know Q12, Q11, Q21 and Q22 say when it is an image and p is a point inside a pixel? A pixel is surrounded by 8 pixels each having some value. How will we decided the corner values of a pixel?

Comment: @PrakashVanapalli you don't. If the coordinate is discrete and it lies on a pixel exactly, the output is that pixel. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, there's no calculation work required. The above formulation is valid for fractional coordinates and you choose the four discrete coordinates that are closest to that coordinate.